# GeoServer 2.22.0 use JSON attribute into SLD Heatmap

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, sld

I am trying to create a heatmap definition in SLD and as value I want to use a property inside a json attribute of the layer.
I have a PostGIS instance connected to the GeoServer, and the attribute column it's defined as Jsonb as in the documentation is explained. https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html?highlight=store#examples
This is how my layer looks like:
[image: Sample of the attributes]

I want to use the "P" property under values feature attribute, so following the documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/postgis.html?highlight=store#examples

I wrote this SLD:

[image]

Unlikely when I try to render the layer using WMS with this SLD Style I got this error about being unable to compare text with numeric:

[image: Error got when try to render the SLD]

I also tried with a shorter decimal number as a comparison and the error is the same, do I have to make a change in the database level?

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351673/how-to-reference-a-postgis-json-field-in-geoserver-sld

Comment: You might need to try one of the conversion functions - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#parsing-and-formatting-functions

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I have to project in the SQL view the properties needed from the jsonb column, I will try a second round with the parsing functions in couple of weeks